# DataGridView VB.net to a list

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, richtextbox

Ok so my dad has around 400 customers for his business and he has a list of customers, his business was going a bit slow so he decided to spend 2 days putting each customers name into this format:

- First and Last Names
- Address and Zip-code

Into one big sheet and then printing it.

I'm working on a program that loads all his customers from a mysql database into datagridview it loads, into ID, First, Last, Phone, Address and Zip-code.

So my question is, how would i be able to select an id number, or multiple id numbers to convert it onto a richtextbox so he could copy it or even print it from there?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run a query. My recommendation is to use [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.ph).

The query should look something like this.

```
 SELECT * FROM `customers` (you could add a WHERE clause also e.g. WHERE id = 1)
```

Next you need to grab the results from that query. You should use [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Once you have the results. You could make a while loop and feet the results into a table, textarea, or anywhere!

Now you know **how** you can do it. :) Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you get the data with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), then store it in a spreadsheet with [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.net).

The query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` ORDER BY `customer_name`
```

If there are multiple rows for one customer, you can also use:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` ORDER BY `customer_name` GROUP BY `customer_name`
```